# Prove that every non-empty finite subset of an ordered set, has maximal and minimal elements.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Assume that $(X,<)$ is a totally ordered set. Prove that if $S$ is a non-empty finite subset of $X$, then $S$ has maximal and minimal elements. Prove this by induction!

**Note:** Intuitively, what we want to prove is obvious; because if $S$ doesn't have maximal and minimal elements, then trichotomy tells us that $S$ doesn't have maximum and minimum elements either. So size of S would be infinite. My problem is showing this infinity with an induction on "w".

Comment: Zorn's lemma and well ordering theorem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single-element set, the element is maximal and minimal.

Assume that all $n$-element subsets have a maximal and a minimal element. Let $A$ sub a subset with $n+1$ elements and $x$ one of its elements. Then $B=A\setminus\{x\}$ has $n$ elements. Let $M,m$ be maximal and minimal elements of $B$. Then $\max(x,M)$ is maximal and $\min(x,m)$ is minimal. In fact, if $y\in A$ and $y\geq \max(M,x)$, then either $y\in B$ or $y=x$. In the first case, it follows that $y=M$ and $M\geq x$. Therefore, $y=\max(M,x)$. In the second case, it follows that $y=x\geq M$ and therefore $y=\max(M,x)$. The argument for $\min(m,x)$ is similar but with the inequalities reversed.

Note that the argument actually shows the existence of maximum and minimum, since the set is assumed to be totally ordered.

Note that although the question includes the condition of totally ordered, the argument can be adapted to also work in this case. What is needed is to replace
$\max(M,x)$ and $\min(m,x)$ for $M$ and $n$, in the case that $M$ and $x$ are not comparable and the case that $m$ and $x$ are not comparable, respectively. In this case, one only gets the existence of maximal and minimal elements, but not necessarily maximum and minimum.

Comment: In the second note, you supposed that the set is not totally ordered. Right?

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh Yes, the condition of totally ordered actually gives you more than maximal and minimal. It gives you existence of maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Let's induct on the size of $S$.

**Base Case:** $|S|=1$

Then, $S = \{a\}$ where $a \in X$, so clearly $S$ has both maximal and minimal element, $a$ being both.

**Inductive Step:** Assume this is true for all sets of size $n$, and let $S = \{a_i\}_{i=0}^n$. Then note that $T = S\setminus \{a_0\}$ has size $n$, and thus has both minimal and maximal elements.

Can you compare both of those to $x_0$ and finish?

Comment: They mean $a_0$ (which is just an arbitrary element of $S$).

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh Typo, sorry. Your $S = \{a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ has $n+1$ elements, so removing $a_0$ leaves $n$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm understanding you correctly, but if you ment $w=|S|$ I think this is easy.

First of all, if $|S|=1$ (or $|S|=0$, it does not matter), the first inductive step is trivial.

Now, if we assume it true for $|S|=n-1,$ let $|S|=n$. We chose a subset of $S$ of order $n-1$ (we have $n$ subsets like that) so we know that it have maximal and minimal elements, $M$ and $m.$ We just need to check wether the element leftover is greater than $M$ or smaller than $m,$ and we can do this because $X$ is a totally ordered set, then so is $S.$

Comment: Let me write the last step and tell me if it is right or not. Let x be the leftover. Then if x>M, x would be the maximal. if x<=M then M is the maximal. For minimal element we can do the same comparison of x and m. Hence the induction is complete. Am I right?

Comment: That's it, you are right. I think the user cardinalRed made that last step too in his answer below. Also I have to mention that we are probably using the axiom of choice to choose that subset with $n-1$ elements.

Comment: @Somerandommathematician: One does not need to appeal to the axiom of choice to fix just **one** certain object with a particular property; that is simply a matter of existential dequantification (i.e. the method of inference that allows one to remove an existential quantifier) after having previously argued that the respective property is indeed fulfilled for at least one object (in other words, that the existential quantification over the predicate expressing that property is indeed a valid statement).

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Oh you are right, I'm just defining the subset by saying what element i take out ,right?

Comment: @ Somerandommathematician w is the natural numbers. I thought we should show with induction that if S doesnt have maximal and minimal, then size of S would be infinite and this would be a contradiction. To show this infinity, I thought one could do an induction such that for every i∈w there exists an element Xi∈S.

Comment: @Somerandommathematician: Precisely! At the inductive step you have a cardinality of $n+1$, number which is never $0$ so your set is therefore nonempty, it contains at least an element, which you go ahead and fix by existential dequantification.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I have just learn the term existential dequantification, kinda cool.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh but you have to say that we are doing induction over the cardinality of $S.$ That you are saying in that comment would be another type of proof.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh: As a matter of notation, w certainly isn't appropriate for the set of natural numbers, the standard notation being $\mathbb{N}$; there are order theory specialists that might tend to denote it by $\omega$, the greek lower-case omega, although such a notation should more rather be reserved to refer to the isomorphism class of $\mathbb{N}$  as a (well-)ordered set, thus making $\omega$ into the least infinite ordinal. As to your "problem of showing this infinity by induction", that is exactly what I talk about in my answer, so do take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

May I propose to you a broader perspective from which you can deduce your result as a particular case.

We say an ordered set $(A, R)$ is **noetherian** if any nonempty subset of $A$ admits at least a maximal element; with this definition in place your quest becomes that of showing that **any finite ordered set is noetherian** (from this it will immediately follow by duality that a finite ordered set is also artinian, which is the notion dual to noetherianity, said to hold for an ordered set in which every nonempty subset admits at least a minimal element).

Let us briefly mention the **fundamental recursion theorem** (itself a special case of a more general theorem of transfinite recursion):

> Given set $A$, element $a \in A$ and map $f: A \to A$ there will exist **a unique sequence** $u \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ satisfying the following conditions:
>
> 1) $u_0=a$
>
> 2) $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

and state the following:

> **Proposition.** For arbitrary ordered set $(A, R)$ the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1) $(A, R)$ is noetherian
>
> 2) **there exists no** strictly increasing (with respect to the order $R$) sequence in $A^{\mathbb{N}}$.

*Proof:*  Arguing by contradiction immediately establishes the implication $1) \Rightarrow 2)$; indeed if under the hypothesis of noetherianity a strictly increasing sequence $a \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$  did exist then the set of all its terms $$a_{\mathbb{N}}=\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$
were on the one hand nonempty yet on the other hand clearly not containing any maximal element (since for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a_n <_R a_{n+1}$).

As for the converse implication, once again we argue by contradiction, assuming that $(A, R)$ were not noetherian; this means that there must exist a nonempty $B \subseteq A$ not containing any maximal element, in other words it must be the case that for any $x \in B$ there will exist $y \in B$ such that $x <_R y$ or equivalently for any $x \in B$ we must have 
$$B \cap (x, \to)_R \neq \varnothing$$
(where I am using the notation $(t, \to)_R=\{x \in A|\ t<_R x\}$).
Therefore, by employing the axiom of choice we can infer the existence of a map $f: B \to B$ such that $f(x) \in B \cap (x, \to)_R$ for any $x \in B$; furthermore, since $B$ is nonempty we can fix a certain $a \in B$.

By applying the fundamental theorem of recursion to the triplet $(B, a, f)$ we obtain a sequence $c \in B^{\mathbb{N}} \subseteq A^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $c_{n+1}=f(c_n)$ for any natural $n$; however, this will entail that $c_n<_R c_{n+1}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which means that $c$ is strictly increasing, amounting to a contradiction. $\Box$

In the particular case of a finite ordered set $A$, property $2)$ is clearly satisfied (otherwise the existence of a strictly monotonic sequence would entail the existence of an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$, which is prohibited by finiteness).

Comment: can you help me understand what AN is? (second part of your Proposition)

Comment: Actually it seems your proof is complete, but its language is hard for me, a student of foundations of mathematics course.

Comment: The equality stated when introducing $a_{\mathbb{N}}$ serves as the definition of that object, definition which I also specified in natural language (that is, using words rather than formal symbols): it is simply the set of all the terms in the mentioned sequence. On another note, let me know if you want more clarifications; my goal was precisely that of introducing a few tools and methods indispensible when working with such foundational objects.

Comment: upon closer analysis, I now realize you must have been asking about $A^{\mathbb{N}}$; in general, the cartesian product $\prod_{i \in I} A_i$ denotes the set of all families of objects indexed by set $I$ and such that for every $i \in I$ the component at index $i$ belongs to $A_i$; in the particular case when $A_i=A$ for all $i$ the previous notation simplifies to $A^I$, the set of all families of elements of $A$ indexed by $I$; in particular, for $I=\mathbb{N}$ we are dealing with all the sequences of elements of $A$ (sequences are by definition families of objects indexed by $\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: (continuation of previous comment) or more generally indexed by upper segments of $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. subsets of the form $\{n \in \mathbb{N}|\ n \geqslant k\}$ for a given natural $k$.